# Как загрузить CSV файл по ссылке?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Хочу загрузить CSV файл в *ipynb* напрямую вот так:

`import pandas as pd`

`df = pd.read_csv('https://www.kaggle.com/sulianova/cardiovascular-disease-dataset?select=cardio_train.csv', sep = ';')`

Но получаю ошибку:

`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 8, saw 2`

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне следует исправить?

Comment: а вы пробовали просто открыть файл по этой ссылке? попробуйте - удивитесь.

Comment: @strawdog именно поэтому я задаю вопрос

Comment: Вы получаете ошибку потому что кагл не отдает вам файл csv, а отдает код страницы сайта, как я могу понять. А страницу сайта pandas прочитать как файл csv не может.

Comment: На той странице, которую вы пытаетесь скачать всего-лишь присутствует ссылка на другую страницу, которая действительно ведет к файлу с данными. Только вот для доступа к этим данным на странице надо авторизоваться.

Comment: https://www.kaggle.com/sulianova/cardiovascular-disease-dataset это ссылка на описание, а в моем вопрос как раз то, о чем вы говорите: ссылка на файл. Я на Каггле авторизован

Comment: @AlexanderAPS, вы авторизированы в браузере, но не в Python - попробуйте открыть приведенный вами URL в Python, например через `requests` и посмотрите, что вы получите...

Comment: то есть, если вы переходите по вашей ссылке в браузере, у вас открывается csv-файл?

Comment: Вы то авторизованы на сайте, а Pandas видимо нет.